# Displaying.Net CLR instead of .Net Framework in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

I have an issue under IIS 10.0.17763.1 and Windows 10:

When I create an App Pool I do not see .Net framework, the only option I have is .Net CLR in the drop down menu. Why? In other versions of IIS and Windows I remember to see always .Net framework...

Comment: `managedRuntimeVersion` should be showed as CLR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/ When they said ".NET Framework" that was a big mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IIS 8.5 I see also *.NET CLR*. It's the actual naming.